# Bulk get using objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using the Objectify Loader ids method to batch load the ids from the google datastore. But from the Google Cloud Trace logs, I can see that this requests are batched in ids of size 10.

Is there any way to increase this size?

However, if I change the consistency level of objectify to Eventual and then do the batch get, then I only see one get call in trace logs.

Can someone explain this behavior and how to increase the batch get limit?

EDIT: Here is the query I am using:

`ofy().load().type(ClassName.class).ids(list of ids)`

Comment: Can you add a code snippet that illustrates how you use Objectify?

Comment: @MrtN I have edited the question to reflect the query I am using